# copy the search box text to the dropdown text in javascript select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

using javacript select2, how do you copy the text from the main search box to the dropdown search box per this image?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P23v.jpg

I've been looking at select2 options like placeholder, templateresult, or tempalteselection but none are working.

Comment: The text from the main search box can be either a placeholder (if no selection was made) or the text from the selected option. What do you want to copy in the dropdown search box?

Comment: as soon as the dropdown is clicked, i want the option box to copy what is shown in the main search box.  The user can then edit the option box any way they want after, without having to update the main search box.

Comment: But the main search box can contain a placeholder (eg: https://select2.org/placeholders - Select a state) or the text of the selected value (eg: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage - Alaska).  Do you want to implement both cases? Or just the text of the selected value?